# RNN prediction values are different after first epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have implemented text multi-class classification using RNN+CNN

Model summary:

```
def get_model():
  input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_len,))
  embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(input)
  layer = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.GRU(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1,
                                                      recurrent_dropout=0.1))(embedding)

  layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, padding="valid", kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform")(layer)

  avg_pool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(layer)
  max_pool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(layer)

  layer = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([avg_pool, max_pool])

  output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(y.value_counts()), activation="sigmoid")(layer)

  model = tf.keras.Model(input, output)

  model.summary()

  return model

model = get_model()
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test), 
    epochs = 1, verbose = 2)
```

---

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_16 (InputLayer)           [(None, 150)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_15 (Embedding)        (None, 150, 100)     88400       input_16[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_12 (Bidirectional (None, 150, 64)      25536       embedding_15[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_12 (Conv1D)              (None, 148, 32)      6176        bidirectional_12[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling1d_12 (Gl (None, 32)           0           conv1d_12[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling1d_12 (Global (None, 32)           0           conv1d_12[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_12 (Concatenate)    (None, 64)           0           global_average_pooling1d_12[0][0]
                                                                 global_max_pooling1d_12[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)                (None, 102)          6630        concatenate_12[0][0]             
==================================================================================================
Total params: 126,742
Trainable params: 38,342
Non-trainable params: 88,400
```

The problem i'm facing is model different prediction result between the 1 epoch and the next epochs.

I ran the model prediction after first epoch. Using sigmoid in last layer. So independent prediction for each classes.

Note:
I have small dataset.

After epoch 1 - prediction:

```
[0.821476 0.178482 0.082908 0.070871 0.244470 0.031154 0.035466 0.869020
 0.413655 0.768583 0.281448 0.188352 0.417780 0.468368 0.535279 0.629149
 0.781784 0.414644 0.218737 0.442238 0.682343 0.358461 0.450273 0.334286
 0.577692 0.215712 0.169237 0.938595 0.180421 0.051505 0.440111 0.387701
 0.257397 0.205229 0.941195 0.019577 0.138571 0.701121 0.568172 0.152105
 0.741303 0.169439 0.035995 0.306321 0.382447 0.268078 0.687641 0.350583
 0.524925 0.945273 0.714135 0.097993 0.102559 0.431982 0.803985 0.231302
 0.246235 0.366514 0.566957 0.411760 0.316942 0.358484 0.102790 0.206971
 0.312865 0.627695 0.293425 0.096269 0.183038 0.310816 0.106294 0.763296
 0.253969 0.219500 0.601052 0.041123 0.257971 0.651815 0.211335 0.488649
 0.414540 0.964665 0.758828 0.552555 0.589932 0.338783 0.445288 0.794278
 0.835401 0.420212 0.514841 0.056917 0.389850 0.232653 0.209908 0.060420
 0.390591 0.324862 0.881604 0.269407 0.196394 0.105344]
```

This is my expected result.

I continued the training to 128 epoch the model accuracy comes around 97. Then, I ran the prediction. Got the following output.

```
[0.000258 0.000269 0.000021 0.000002 0.000009 0.000007 0.000023 0.000053
 0.001453 0.000074 0.000039 0.000060 0.000050 0.000009 0.000628 0.000155
 0.001590 0.000133 0.000078 0.000083 0.000039 0.000106 0.000632 0.000037
 0.000021 0.000903 0.000020 0.001508 0.000322 0.000001 0.000003 0.000063
 0.000002 0.000009 0.000095 0.000130 0.000085 0.000185 0.000062 0.000014
 0.000113 0.000009 0.000001 0.000006 0.000001 0.000021 0.000043 0.000003
 0.000273 0.026851 0.002266 0.000087 0.000055 0.000084 0.000006 0.000001
 0.000119 0.000007 0.014515 0.001661 0.000006 0.001226 0.002544 0.000142
 0.000108 0.000063 0.000173 0.000050 0.000012 0.000078 0.000012 0.000016
 0.000028 0.000024 0.000240 0.000128 0.000004 0.000016 0.000008 0.000048
 0.000045 0.000511 0.000209 0.000076 0.000031 0.000031 0.000330 0.000001
 0.000090 0.000128 0.000007 0.000024 0.000032 0.000077 0.000026 0.000008
 0.000379 0.000080 0.004676 0.000004 0.000351 0.000041]
```

The decimal points are went to too lower. I can't threshold values with this lower decimal. What went wrong here?

Comment: Nobody can tell you what went wrong, the model is learning so the predictions are always changing, please include full code to see if there is something wrong.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro added the model code

Answer (score 2):

For multi-label classification, what you call "independent predictions", you have to use the `binary_crossentropy` loss:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Since you were using sparse categorical crossentropy, its likely that your labels are integers, you need to encode them as binary vectors (1 for class, 1 for non-class) for this to actually work.

Comment: I want the independent result of the classes
Ref: https://androidkt.com/multi-label-text-classification-in-tensorflow-keras/
First epoch I got the exact result I need. But its not last longer :(

Comment: Your question says multi class classification, not multi label

Comment: Yes. Also I did mentioned that, independent prediction for each classes.

Comment: You have to use the right terms, anyways see updated answer.

Comment: What labels are you using?

Comment: Converted the labels by scikit label encoder. Again converted encoded integer to binary using with keras tocategorical.

Comment: to_categorical is for one hot encoding, not for multi label encoding

Comment: Oh. Which one I use? @Matis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195770/discussion-between-giri-annamalai-m-and-matias-valdenegro).